# How can one prove one has entered a country?

Tags: international-travel

Looking at [Have we visited all the countries / territories as a community?](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3907/1810) or [Have more people been to space than visited every nation?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/54143/7654), I wonder the following:  How can one prove one has entered a country?

Some cases are easy such as a stamp on one's passport upon entering the country, but some cases are more difficult such as a visa-exempt entry to Mexico via land border.

Comment: Prove to whom? Are you doing a competition? So set the rule. Ticket? Selfies? An invoice/receipt (for some local services, like drink/eat/sleep)? Or just trust.

Comment: Many countries like Singapore and Australia don't stamp passports now.

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi just curious in general, I was wondering how a proof could look like when people make travel claims such as in https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3907/1810 or [Have more people been to space than visited every nation?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/54143/7654). Also the visited country list sometimes comes up in paperwork eg during the naturalization process in the US.

Comment: I was recently in Jamaica for a day.  No receipts, no hotel charges, I took a handful of photos but I'm not in any of them, no stamp in my passport.  I have no idea how I'd prove I was there for the day

Answer (score 7):

As nobody knows whether your name really is Franck and the account picture shows your own face, there is no way to prove this on Travel.SE.

More generally speaking:

- Get your passport stamped upon entry

  This obviously works, but depending on where you are coming from and into which country you travel, there will be no stamps (or even border controls).
- Take a selfie in front of a landmark
- Show the bill (with your name) of a hotel
- Get fined (or even jailed) and have a report of it with your name on it.
- Get yourself into a local newspaper, TV station or similar
- Speak at a well-known (and documented/published/streamed) event in the country

Obviously, any "proof" based on data/pictures you provide yourself can easily be faked with Photoshop or other means. So an independent validation of your presence (as in the last two points above) is prefered.

Comment: Have several in person payments on your bank account.

Comment: @Willeke Payments can get pretty complicated. I once paid for tickets in Australian dollars with an Australian credit card at a tourist trap in Australia, and was charged a foreign exchange fee because the company routes it through their HQ in Europe. (Eat a bag of dicks, Merlin! And yes, I got the fee reverted after complaining.)

Comment: @Willeke The problem with all proofs which rely on information you provide yourself (like a screenshot of your account statement) is that they can be easily forged. Making the news (so there is reporting channel independent of yourself) is probably the easiest way to a (at least very hard to forge) verification.

Comment: @nohillside I'd say that in our current age any sort of image/document "proof" can be faked for the casual viewer by a well motivated liar using various editing tools.  So the veracity of any self supplied proof will always boil down "trust" in the person supplying it.  IMHO that would only leave your last two points as valid, independent proof of being somewhere.  D'oh.  In my half asleep state I just realized that I simply parroted your own comment.  I'll delete my comment later today.

Comment: @PeterM Never mind, I take it as confirmation :-)

Answer (score 7):

> How can one prove one has entered a country?

You will have to ask whoever wants that proof (for whatever purpose)

If an entity requires "proof" they typically will also define exactly what types of proof are acceptable and which are not. That will vary greatly from one situation to another. That's especially the case if "proof" is needed for some legal reasons.

A geo tag on your phone or a hotel bill may be good for friends and family but maybe not for a criminal investigator.

Comment: "You will have to ask whoever wants that proof (for whatever purpose)". I was also interested in this question to see how I could check if someone did go to a given country. (check with their consent/collaboration, no intent to be sneaky). I agree, geo tagging corroborated by some travel bills would be a strong indicator.

Comment: Sorry, I still don't get it. Why would you, as a private person, need to verify that someone has been to a specific country or not? I could understand if you were to hire someone to frequently travel to a certain country and you want to know how much cultural  hands-on experience they have.  But in this case some well chosen interview questions would work a lot better than "proof of travel".